# PDO bind params in looping array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently I'm building a PDO insert similar to this:

```
foreach($r->occurrences as $row) {
   $arr[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'start' => $row->getTimestamp(),
        'end' => $row->getTimestamp() + $duration,
        'note' => $notes
    );
};

$keys = implode(',', array_keys($arr[0]));

// Format into ('1','2','4'),('8','3','4') for insertion
foreach ($repBkgArr as &$array) {
   $array = "('".implode("','", $array)."')";
}

$values = implode(',', $arr);

$query = "INSERT INTO table ($keys) VALUES $values";

$db->execute($query);
```

In this case I can't obviously just bind the variables in the second parameter of the execute function because I'm batch inserting several sets of data.

```
$db->execute($query, array(':id' => $id, ':name' => $name);
```

How can I deal with this? I've been researching all day and I don't seem to be able to find anything that I can apply to my situation.

Comment: Instead of batch inserting, you could just prepare the statement for one set, and then loop over the list to execute it with varying parameters. That's kind of the point of prepared statements. :)

Comment: Silly question... Does looping over a prepared statement execute as multiple queries? I need to make sure I limit how often I hit the DB and there are potentially thousands of 'batches' in this query

Comment: Your data hits the server either way. With a prepared statement, you'll simply pass the data with multiple packets, instead of one long-winded data blob consuming heaps of memory on both ends. Just use a transaction to simulate a single batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: just add index prefix for each bind value like this:

```
$sql     = 'INSERT INTO `tabke`(id, name) VALUES ';
$bind    = array();
$sqlRows = array();
foreach ($r->occurrences as $index => $row) {
    $sqlRows[] = "(:id_$index, :name_$index)";
    $bind[':id_'.$index]   = $row['id'];
    $bind[':name_'.$index] = $row['name'];
}

print_r($sql.implode(',', $sqlRows));   // QUERY SQL
print_r($bind);                         // QUERY PARAMS
```